# Does p90x ab-ripper work?

Tags: abdominals

I recently found out about the p90x training program, but what interests me the most is it's ab-ripper. Has anyone tried it before? Any input is appreciated... :)

Comment: Care to explain what the ab-ripper workout consist off? That way we can judge it based on those merits.

Comment: I don't know exactly how they call all the routines. But it comprises of lower and upper ab exercises of 25 reps each and only a couple of seconds rests in between. when you make a search at youtube, you'll see how it's done...

Comment: Well, to get a better answer it would help if you did the searching for everyone who wanted to answer your question ;-) Surely there's a site who has reviewed or looked at the workout?

Comment: Ab Ripper X consists of 12 routines each routine with 25 reps.  Routines are performed with little to no rest in between.

Comment: Yes, the exercises will give you the six-pack, which is only seen after you've reached a certain body fat percentage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've watched part of the Ab Ripper X video, and reviewed all the exercises involved, and while I've not tried the program particularly, I have used several of the exercises that they have in their routine in my workouts in the past and can say with absolute certainty that the exercises will build muscle and burn calories.

How many calories you will burn I could not state for certain. Also, there is a limit to how far this workout will take you, and at that point, you'll need to add more reps, more resistance, or increase the intensity in some other more creative way in order to continue to progress.

If you are overweight or have excess fat on your stomach, having strong stomach muscles will not make your stomach look less fatty or more ripped/toned. You'll need to lose the fat to show off the muscles. Losing the fat involves a change in diet and/or activity level, probably beyond what you're going to get just from the Ab Ripper X routine.

Ab Ripper X is a fairly intense workout, especially for a beginner or someone not already in decent shape, and as Meade Rubenstein pointed out, starting out with too intense a workout often causes beginners to lose interest and quit. Building a stronger, healthier you is a lifestyle change with a lifetime commitment.

Comment: +1 ab ripper x is intense even for people with strong abs

Comment: FYI I wore my watch the other day when I did Ab Ripper X and I burned 190 calories while I did the exercises. And that was while doing modified versions! :D

Answer (score 7):

From what I know of the p90X program, it's an intense program based on High Impact Interval Training (HIIT), that alternates exercises every 3-4 weeks to keep the body's adoption to the specific set of exercises from happening.  The few people I know who have tried it have seen results, but none have stayed with it long term - the problem with fad exercises and diets...it doesn't set the stage for long term personal changes due to it's required intensity to work.  So, specific to the ab ripper - it probably does 'work' if you're looking to burn calories.  If you're looking for the '6 pack' goal, you're better off focusing on a well rounded, long term exercise program. IMO

Answer (score 2):

The P90X program definitely works. Ab ripper X works. It is very intense and there were a couple of exercises I still couldn't quite do as well as others after I had been on the program for a month.

There is a fit test in the P90X program that will determine whether or not you will be able to do the exercises so do that first. The Ab-Ripper X video is about 10-20 minutes long, (I can't really remember) but it is really intense.

There is also a diet plan that you are supposed to follow, including buying pills and protein shakes from the Beachbody company, but I didn't do that. I think that the videos are enough, but you probably won't get the results that you want from just the ab ripper video.

You aren't supposed to do the workout everyday, and Tony Horton says that in the video as well. You are really supposed to be working on a different set of muscles everyday. I think in my program I did ab ripper x three times a week after my normal workout.

Answer (score 2):

P90x Ab-Ripper does, in fact, work.  I got into a routine of doing it every other day during a 6 month period where I couldn't otherwise do any workouts.  My core got noticeably stronger and within 8 weeks or so you can see increased definition in your core, provided you have reasonably low body fat.

I also modified the workout a little to make it more effective for me. Specifically, I (a) memorized the moves so I could do the workout even if I didn't have access to the video, (b) started out with 20 reps instead of 25, then worked my way up eventually to 30 reps as I could, (c) gave myself a flat 30 second break between each exercise, which helped me keep good form but toned down the 'cardio' effect, and (d) rotated the moves.  Every day I would shift my starting move up one, so on day 1 I would start with move 1, and the next workout I would start with move 2 and add move 1 to the end.  I think that keeps things from getting static, keeps you from getting bored, and also gives you an opportunity to do every exercise "fresh" at some point.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the ab ripper works great even for those in shape. If you watch the video you will see some of the individuals have ripped abs, and you can see they are getting a good workout. People reading this must remember a couple of things. Ab x is part of a whole workout program. The other workouts such as yoga x, chest n back, legs n back, shoulders n arms, x stretch, and plyometrics hit the abs in some way or another during the week. The day ab ripper is done, you should have also performed legs n back or chest n back. If abs are easy for you do legs n back first then abs. Same for chest n back. With that, the person doing ab ripper will get out of it what they put into it. I know, I have been doing a modified p9ox since finishing the program 2 years ago.

Comment: l33t speak and abbreviations are frowned upon on SE sites.

Comment: I'm skeptical that working your shoulders and arms can be the key to an effective ab workout.